# Controlling External Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

Here is what I'm trying to do:

My application has a feature allowing a document generated to be faxed. This feature prints the document to a Printer that is set up in the system as a Fax printer. Its a Brother, and the printer name is Brother PC-FAX. Currently, when the print job is initiated, the print driver opens a dialog box for inputting the fax number, cover sheet options, and what not. The fax number associated with the document is stored. I am trying to set up my app to inject the fax number for the user, and click the "Start" button.
The dialog has shortcuts, it initially focuses a button, and the user can press Shift+TAB to get to the number input control, which then accepts Ctrl+V to paste. Then the user can press Alt+O to activate the "Start" button. My previous app version simply copied the fax number to the clipboard, and left the paste and click actions to the user, but I'm trying to automate further. My current approach is

1. Hijack WndProc to answer the WM_ACTIVATE message
2. If the Window caption is "Brother PC-FAX", then
3. Use SendKeys.Send() to send "+{TAB}", "^V", and "%O"

This would work, except when the actual fax dialog seems to not register as an actual window, as in, perhaps its just a dialog box child form of the print driver. The only window caption I come up with is the "Printing" box, which is the small window that pops up everytime you print, on any printer. This does not allow the SendKeys functions to pass through.

Any thoughts as to how I should handle this? It would be nice if the driver had and SDK that would allow customized command calls, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, at least I figured out "A" method. If anyone has a better or more efficient idea please let me know, but here is how I solved it:

1. On print action, set clipboard text to fax number
2. create background worker to handle the printing
3. after starting the background print job, sleep the current thread for 5 seconds, giving the fax dialog time to get front and center
4. Use SendKeys.SendWait command for the "+{TAB}" and "^V" commands, then just SendKeys.Send for the final "%O" command

This works, but I can see problems down the road if system performance degrades causing the print job to slow, exceeding the 5 second sleep cycle. This cycle could be increased, but maybe there's a better way still?